# Instagram API search by tag, blank return

Tags: instagram-api

I'm trying to use the search by tag API to return the JSON result, but it returned a blank result.

This is the API request format from their website. I only set the tag-name & access token parameters.
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{tag-name}/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN

I already set my access token's scope as public_content so that I can use this particular API.

However, the result I got is:

```
{
    "pagination": {
        "deprecation_warning": "next_max_id and min_id are deprecated for this endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id instead"
    }, 
    "meta": {
        "code": 200
    }, 
    "data": []
}
```

Which was basically nothing. I read that I should be expecting max & min ids. I had already checked that the hashtag I'm searching has more than 200 entries, so there should be more than one page.

No issues with other insta APIs when searching by userids, just can't get it to work on this and searching by recent media.

Really appreciate any help. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the looks of things, you're getting a deprecation warning because you are passing the `next_max_id` and `min_id` parameters in your request.

As mentioned in the result you got, you should use `min_tag_id` and `max_tag_id` instead (if you want these parameters in your request). This is mentioned in the [Instagram Developer documentation](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/)

> **ACCESS_TOKEN**  A valid access token.
>
> **COUNT**         Count of tagged media to return.
>
> **MIN_TAG_ID**    Return media before this min_tag_id.
>
> **MAX_TAG_ID**    Return media after this max_tag_id.

Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by "expecting max & min ids". If you mean you're expecting them in the response, then this is a wrong expectation.

Also, another possible cause for your problem is the recent [Instagram Platform update](http://developers.instagram.com/post/133424514006/instagram-platform-update), which has forced all clients created after November 17th, 2015 to be in Sandbox mode and go through a review process. If you are affected by this, note that your results will be "filtered" depending on the Sandbox users you have (in which case, you might not have the number of results you were expecting).

Comment: Thanks Jason, I think most likely it is because I am in Sandbox mode~ Didn't realised it has this restriction. Have to wait for them to approve I suppose... Thanks though!

Comment: Just to clarify, I did not pass through the nex_max_id and min_id at all; hence was expecting the min_tag_id & max_tag_id to yield from the API output (where I only put in the tag name and access token parameters)

Comment: Ah ok, sorry my bad. But yeah I think it's probably to do with the Sandbox mode then. Let me know if it works once they approve!

Comment: Seems like instagram only grant 3 types of users to their live api: (1) My app allows people to login with Instagram and share their own content. (2) My product helps brands and advertisers understand, manage their audience and media rights. (3)  My product helps broadcasters and publishers discover content, get digital rights to media, and share media with proper attribution.

I do not fall under this list unfortunately. I think I will just have to go to the normal insta website search and pull the results from the html...